# I need help identifying DC/DC converter AH4V55V5S-1W

Tags: dc-dc-converter, step-up

[image: AH4V55V5S-1W]

I need some help identifying the component in the picture above. It is a step-up DC/DC converter. Input is approximately 5V from USB converted to +/- 6.8V. It is used in Micsig’s differential probe. Google search for “AH4V55V5S-1W” only refers me to eevblog. I looked at websites such as RS and mouser and could not find anything similar. Usual output voltages are 5V, 9V, 12V.

Comment: I suspect it's got an in-house part number, and was sold only to Micsig for their probe.  Those things are modules, with a plain ol' circuit board potted into a case, so it wouldn't be hard for the manufacturer to change the output voltage setting on a standard product.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I only require a single unit so I do not think any changes to the product would be possible. I will investigate the rest of the board and see if it can handle +/- 9V as +/- 5V could degrade the performance (all voltage rails to op-amps drop).